# How to launch game using a 'Launch' button in the website?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, launcher

It is an online game, I need to develop a 'Launch' button on the game site to launch the client side game. I have seen this in several online games [like this one](http://crossfire.z8games.com).
How can this be done?

Note: I am using ASP.NET to develop the website.

Answer (score 1):

If the game is an .exe you're going to have trouble due to security.  (ie if you could issue commands to be run on the client you could execute viruses etc)

If the game is done in flash or silverlight then there are other options.

Comment: nope, it is in XNA. (i.e. .exe)
I know about these security issues but I believe that there is some way around that asks for the user confirmation or so. I have seen this several times but do not know how it is done.

Comment: Well, the nice thing about javascript is it's not compiled.  If you can find one, peek a look at their javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar solutions with Java Webstart (jnlp files).